# What happens if you detach a thread that's executing a permanent loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is this the equivalent of a leak? To use pointers and dynamically allocated memory as an analogy, if I lose a pointer to a resource that I've allocated memory for I can't delete or free that memory anymore. Likewise if I have a worker thread that's running an infinite loop and I detach the thread then is that a leak? There's no way to stop the thread executing if it's been detached?

Comment: If you lose track of the thread and it never stops executing, it is impossible to `join` again, so sure, maybe? Yet is it doing important work or not? Thread leaks are usually a problem if you create threads you need to kill later, but can't because you lost your handle. If you never need to kill it, then the handle is mostly just for checking up on it.

Comment: What happens when... what? It's not clear what you're looking for here. You seem to know what happens if you detach a thread. So... what are you asking for?

Answer (score 1):

What happens is the thread keeps running, potentially forever.  If the thread decides on its own to exit, it will clean up its own internal data structures so there won't be any memory leak (at least, not from the thread-class itself; detaching the thread object tells it not to expect any parent thread to do cleanup via `join()`, so the exiting thread will do that cleanup itself).  If it keeps running, then whatever resources it has allocated will remain allocated, although technically it's not a memory leak because code in the thread itself still (presumably) has the ability to free those resources, if it wanted to.

There is still a way to stop the thread from executing; you simply have to ask it nicely to exit.  How you ask it is up to you -- you could do it by setting a `std::atomic<bool> pleaseQuit;` variable to true, and relying on the thread to periodically check the variable's value and exit if it's true, or by sending a byte to the thread on a pipe or a socket, or by some other means.  This does require the co-operation of the code running inside the thread, of course; there's no good/safe way to unilaterally kill an uncooperative thread.

Once you've asked the thread to stop running, you usually want to then block until you know that it the thread is guaranteed dead, e.g. so that you can safely deallocate data structures that the thread might try to access while it still exists.  To do that, you'll need to `join()` the thread, which means you shouldn't `detach()` it since detached threads can't be joined.  Detached threads are only useful in situations where you don't care about cleaning up (e.g. because you're not expecting the thread to ever stop running anyway)

Comment: When the main thread [the program] exits what happens to that thread running and was detached?

Comment: It keeps running until the OS deallocates the process, at which point the OS unilaterally kills it.  Note that allowing a thread to keep running until the OS deallocates the process can cause occasional crashes, if the thread accesses any data structures that get deallocated when main() returns.

Comment: @Zebrafish: "*When the main thread [the program] exits what happens to that thread running and was detached?*" As far as the standard is concerned, behavior is undefined in that case.

Comment: If you have detached threafs running, you could call your 'terminateProcess()' OS API, rather than  returning from main().